# New to Android programming, have a few questions about format and style for an app

Tags: java, android, layout, mediawiki, mobile-website

I am new to Android programming and my first app has to do with a Wikia page.  The current way that I have it set up right now my app will pull a list of the categories and put them in a listview for the user to click.  Once the user clicks it redirects them to the mobile page for the category/item that they chose.

I was wondering is this good practice for an app to redirect to the mobile site, or should I find a way to pull the info from the site into my app?  Is either way better than the other?  Please give me as many opinions as you have good or bad, I want to know so I can make this the best that I can.

Answer (score 3):

Theee is no need to redirect the user to the browser or a webView since you can parse the data with the [WikiMedia API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php)
You can also checkout the [official Wikipedia Android App](https://github.com/wikimedia/WikipediaMobile) from Github, but it's not an native Android app(It's build with phonegap)

Comment: Oh ok thank you for that, I wasn't aware that I could pull the data with the WikiMedia API.  When I figure out how to do this do you know if it just pulls XML data that I would have to convert, or would it pull the actual text where I could load it into a string to display? and like-wise with images?  Thank you again!